# d3 v5 position a pin image on map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to render USA map. I am able to position circles as pins on map using cx and cy attribute of circle tag of svg using Long Lat. But now I want to position images or html tags on the map. Question is how can I calculate position of image tag or div tag using long lat. Here is example of my code.

```
<circle
    key={marker.id}
    cx={ projection(props)([`${long}`, `${lat}`])[0] }
    cy={ projection(props)([`${long}`, `${lat}`])[1] }
    r={ 10 }
    fill="#E91E63"
    className="marker"
/>
```

and the projection function.

```
const projection = (props) => {
    return geoAlbersUsa()
      .scale(props.width)
      .translate([ props.width / 2, props.height / 2 ]);
}
```

Comment: SVG has an image tag, just use it in place of the circle....

Comment: used image tag with x and y attributes. Thanks.